# How can i close 5555 port at android with ADB shell

Tags: android, port, remote-access

I created a wmware server with android system and installed the Remote ADB Shell(RAS) program.
Now i can connect to an android device with ip address and 5555 port. So what i want is, close this 5555 port with RAS and doesnt need to go to the near device.

I tried creating a file with below settings but it doesnt work. Can anyone tell me anyting about it? I need to close 5555 port an android device and cannot go near the device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `the command below` but if you have set up a listener on port `5555 using`

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

and then connected to the device using

```
adb connect ip:5555
```

and now you're done with your connection and simply want to stop the device from listening on port 5555, you can use the command

```
adb -s ip:5555 usb
```

to end the listening mode over the network on port 5555 and it will "close" the connection to your device remotely.

Example:

```
$ adb tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
$ adb connect 192.168.50.157
connected to 192.168.50.157:5555
$ adb -s 192.168.50.157:5555 usb
restarting in USB mode
$ adb connect 192.168.50.157
failed to connect to '192.168.50.157:5555': Connection refused
```